# Really weird state behaviour when trying to set it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've had so much issues with State in React while learning it, but this one is new. So I have a variable that holds the default value (bike data). I then put it inside a State and render the page with it.

I also have a function which when triggered sorts the default data by year.

```js
import BikeCard from "../components/BikeCard";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import { getAllBikes } from "../lib/bikes";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useState } from "react";
import BikeGallery from "../components/BikeGallery";

export default function Home({ data }) {
    const allBikes = []; // Default data
    data.forEach((model) => model.bikes.forEach((bike) => allBikes.push(bike)));
    const [displayData, setDisplayData] = useState(allBikes);
    const [sortType, setSortType] = useState("make"); // Trying to delete this

    const SortByInputHandler = (e) => {
        setSortType(e.target.value); // Trying to delete this
        if (e.target.value === "year") {
            setDisplayData(sortByYear(allBikes)); // Sort the default data by year and store it into State
        } else if (e.target.value === "make") {
            setDisplayData(allBikes);
        }
    };
    const sortByYear = (data) => {
        let arr = data;
        arr.sort((a, b) => {
            return b.year > a.year ? 1 : b.year < a.year ? -1 : 0;
        });
        return arr;
    };
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Head>
                <title>Ride 4 - Bikes</title>
            </Head>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>Sort by:</label>
                    <select onChange={SortByInputHandler}>
                        <option value="make">Make</option>
                        <option value="year">Year</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <BikeGallery displayData={displayData} />
        </Layout>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const data = getAllBikes();
    return {
        props: { data },
    };
}
```

The weird thing is that when I try to delete the `sortType` state the state stops updating. No errors, nothing. The UI just doesn't update if I delete the `sortType` state even tho it's not used anywhere.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Just wanted to clarify that the code works as it is above. It only stops working if I delete the lines of code which I've marked with a comment that I want to delete. The `sortType` state is never used anywhere, so I don't know why when deleted the component stops updating.

SOLVED:

As the guys in the comments explained. The `sort` function changes the original array, which is no good when trying to update the state.

The solution was to change:

`let arr = data`

to

`let arr = [...data]`

which creates a new array.

Final code:

```js
import BikeCard from "../components/BikeCard";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import { getAllBikes } from "../lib/bikes";
import Head from "next/head";
import { useState } from "react";
import BikeGallery from "../components/BikeGallery";

export default function Home({ data }) {
    const allBikes = [];
    data.forEach((model) => model.bikes.forEach((bike) => allBikes.push(bike)));
    const [displayData, setDisplayData] = useState(allBikes);

    const SortByInputHandler = (e) => {
        if (e.target.value === "year") {
            setDisplayData(sortByYear(allBikes));
        } else if (e.target.value === "make") {
            setDisplayData(allBikes);
        }
    };
    const sortByYear = (data) => {
        let arr = [...data];
        arr.sort((a, b) => {
            return b.year > a.year ? 1 : b.year < a.year ? -1 : 0;
        });
        return arr;
    };
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Head>
                <title>Ride 4 - Bikes</title>
            </Head>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <label>Sort by:</label>
                    <select onChange={SortByInputHandler}>
                        <option value="make">Make</option>
                        <option value="year">Year</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <BikeGallery displayData={displayData} />
        </Layout>
    );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const data = getAllBikes();
    return {
        props: { data },
    };
}
```

Comment: `sort` mutates the original array. This means `setDisplayData` is not triggering a re-render. However the `setSortType` *is* triggering a re-render. This is why when you remove that code, you stop seeing the updates

Comment: Solution: `let arr = data` => `let arr = [...data]`

Comment: I generally prefer `data.slice().sort(.....)` as it's a bit more succinct, but yes, sort mutates the array in-place so a copy is necessary first.

Comment: so has @BrianThompson  said the `setDisplayData` function just sorts your array , array values are passed by reference in javascript, so if you sort the items in the array you, the reference to that array is still the same just that the item in the array has been updated, so react does not see that has a state change , so when you want to updated and array state, you do that by changing the state's references which is done my making a new array from the old array, which can be easy done using the spread operator

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks that fixed the problem